# BASH Linux : syntax error « ;; »

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax

i have a syntax error « ;; »

```
Syntax error near unexpected token « ;; »
```

my code

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu

clear

echo "Decryptor"

PS3='entrez votre chois: '
options=("update" "decryptor" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "update")
            php updatekey.php
            break
            ;;
        "decryptor")
           #Nom de la video
           read -p "Nom de la série  : " name
           #detection du fichier .png
           find . -name "*.png" | while read line
           oname="$(basename "${line}" .png)"
           #décryption du fichier png
           php -e AES.class.php "${oname}".png
           #on change le nom du fichier
           mv "${oname}".ass "${name}".ass

           read -p "voulez vous télécharger la video (Y/N)? "
           [ "$(echo $REPLY | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])" == "y" ] || exit

           read -p "entrez liens   :" src
           read -p "liens vod" vod

           rtmpdump -v -T '567ghgh' -r "$vod" -a "vod" -f "WIN 13,0,0,182" -W "http://yoyo.com/components/yoyo.swf" -p  "http://yoyo.com" -y "mp4:$src" -o "$name.mp4"
             break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

is part of code with error 
why I get an error I modified the script a bit and this part to not move and I now have an error

What can be the cause

thank you :)

Comment: You need to show us the part of the code just above, starting with `case`.

Comment: This code is not sufficiently complete to reproduce the bug. Test that a given piece of code **produces the exact bug you're reporting when used on its own** before posting it in a question. (Taking out pieces of code _not_ needed to reproduce the bug is even better).

Comment: I give you my complete code

Comment: The `[ $(echo $REPLY | ...` part is hopelessly convoluted. `case $REPLY in [yY]) ;; *) exit ;; esac` isn't syntactically much simpler but avoids unquoted string expansion and external processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 21 contains the beginning of an incomplete `while` statement. The parser only notices because `;;` is illegal when it's still looking for the `do`.

```
find stuff | while read line
    echo you can have multiple commands here --
    echo the exit code of the expression is
    echo examined by '"while"'
do
    echo ... Body of while loop
done
```

Your code lacks the `do` and `done` parts, and it's unclear to Bash (and to us) where they should go.